# Prime number of the form $A^{B^C}+D^{E^F}$

Tags: prime-numbers

My Brother asked me what is the smallest prime number of the form $A^{B^C}+D^{E^F}$ where A,B,C are three distinct prime numbers, and D,E,F are 3 distinct primes that is Permutations of those 3 primes.I realize that we must arrange the exponents to be as smallest as possible in order to get smallest prime as possible.So what is the smallest such prime? (and second smallest :-)

Comment: Note that large primes are odd, so $A$ or $D$ must be equal to $2$

Comment: @MarkBennet ,yes,but I am not sure that F must be 2

Comment: Curiously, $2^{(5^3)}+3^{(2^5)}$ is prime.

Comment: @bonsoon are you sure it is a prime ?

Comment: At least according to WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=isprime%282%5E5%5E3%2B3%5E2%5E5%29

Comment: @NeilRoy 1 isn't prime.

Comment: @NeilRoy A, B, C, D, E, and F ALL must be prime.

Answer (score 4):

$A = 2$ OR $D = 2$

$A \neq D$, $B \neq E$, $C \neq F$

$a^n$ generally increases faster as $n \rightarrow \infty$ than as $a$ does.

If we say that $A = 2$, then $A^{B^C}$ must be even. Therefore, $D^{E^F}$ must be odd.

Therefore we have $2^{B^C} + D^{2^F}$ OR $2^{B^C} + D^{F^2}$

Let's try $2^{5^3}+3^{2^5}$. It is prime! Are there any smaller primes of the specified form? Taking $2^{B^C} + D^{2^F}$, we have two cases: is $5^3 < 3^5$ and is $2^5 < 5^2$. The first cases is true, but the second case is not. Therefore, let's try varying the second case. Is $2^{5^3}+3^{5^2}$ prime? It is not! Therefore, $2^{5^3}+3^{2^5}$ is the answer!

Comment: If $D$ is odd, every power of $D$ is odd, regardless of whether the exponent is odd or even.

Comment: @Joffan $D^{E^F}$ must be a permutation of $A^{B^C}$

Comment: If we assume the first term is $2^{X^Y}$, the second term can be either $X^{Y^2}$ or $Y^{2^X}$

Comment: @Joffan It has to be $Y^{2^X}$

Comment: @Joffan nvm, you are right. I will edit.

Comment: @Joffan fixed :)